# Is it Okay to Ignore GL_INVALID_OPERATION Caused by Calling `wglGetProcAddress` Inside `glBegin`/`glEnd`?

Tags: opengl

I discovered recently that calling `wglGetProcAddress(...)` between calls to `glBegin(...)` and `glEnd()` produces a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.  Evidently, (from [the most technical source I could find](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2014-October/069010.html)):

> The MS opengl32.dll library apparently calls glFlush from
>   wglGetProcAddress().  If we're inside glBegin/End(), glFlush
>   will dispatch to _mesa_generic_nop() and we'll generate a
>   GL_INVALID_OPERATION error.

The generated function pointer is null, but trying again with `GetProcAddress(...)` produces a valid function pointer, and the program seems to continue happily.

My question: is ignoring the error (i.e. `glGetError()`) okay?

---

Edit: why would I want to do this?  Loading OpenGL functions is overhead, and doing it lazily is a performance concern on slower hardware (this approach is used e.g. in glbinding).  It's a big deal if you have multiple contexts and you want to only use a subset of the functionality in each, or if you're creating/deleting contexts frequently.  My code implements every API function by a dynamically backed store, so unloaded functions also save space, which is important on smaller systems and becomes significant with many contexts.

Comment: You *could* just switch to VBOs...

Comment: @DietrichEpp I'm writing an GL loading library, so that is not relevant.

Comment: Why not just load all the functions once, at the beginning, that way you don't need to `wglGetProcAddress()` in the middle of program execution?

Comment: @imallett: using `GetProcAddress()` is not the same as `wglGetProcAdress()`, and only the latter one should be used to query GL extension function pointers. Note that this is not only a theoretical problem, but can also fail miserably in practice.

Comment: @derhass: Why? What is wrong with `wglGetProcAddress()`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: `wglGetProcAddress()` is fine, and I did not claim otherwise. My comment was directed at imallett, who seems to use `GetProcAdress()`, which is just directly resolving symbols from the loaded DLLs, and completely bypasses windows' OpenGL ICD mechanism.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which function are you calling between `glBegin (...)` and `glEnd (...)` that needs to be loaded through the extension loading mechanism? Depending on what it is, you might be able to hoist the first call outside `glBegin (...)` / `glEnd (...)` block and that will make sure your lazy loading happens outside instead of inside.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell whether you've found undefined behaviour or just a mis-implemented specification. In either case, these things might break easily with future versions of the libraries involved, and I think you should find another way of getting OpenGL function pointers than in the middle of drawing your graphics.